# 8086 Interrupt 21h , 02h doesn't print anything

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, emu8086

I am trying to print decimal numbers by converting them into characters, although I succeeded in splitting the number into two digits, I can't print them and I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
.MODEL small
.STACK 64
.DATA

.CODE

MAIN PROC FAR
         MOV   AX,@DATA
         MOV   DS,AX

         mov   ax,15
         mov   bx,10
         div   bx
    ;result in al
    ;remainder in dl
         mov   bl,DL
         mov   bh,al

         add   bl,'0'
         add   bh,'0'

         MOV   AH,02H
         MOV   DL,bh
         INT   21H

         MOV   AH,02H
         MOV   DL,bl
         INT   21H

         hlt
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

Any idea why my code doesn't print the characters??

Comment: You should be zeroing out DX before the div because the division by a 16-bit register will result in dividing the 32-bit number in DX:AX by the register BX (in your case). What results do you get printed and what did you expect to be printed?

Comment: @MichaelPetch thank you MOV DX,0 solved the problem thank you ... I didn't get any output but now I get 15